# No If-Modified-Since header when using ng-src (for caching)

Tags: spring, angularjs, caching, spring-mvc

I am trying to ensure that my images are cached.  My spring controller implements a check to see if the image has changed since the last modified time ( http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-lastmodified )

The problem is that ngSrc / ng-src is not sending up the If-Modified-Since header.  Is there a way to make this happen?  Am I doing something wrong?

**It looks like SpringMVC is adding no-cache headers to the original image, so that could be the cause of the problem - investigating how to turn them off!**

Comment: do you have cache disabled in browser? looking in wrong place at `ng-src`, all it does is update `src` of tag and browser handles request as it would for any other image

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I don't have cache disabled (I am getting other 304 responses - including some images).

Comment: @Muhammad Sorry, that's not correct - have a look at https://httpstatuses.com/304